# How to convert number of days to date format of years, months, and days

Tags: mysql

I try to get number of years, months, and days from number days. I tried this:

```
SELECT enddate,startdate,extract(month from enddate)-extract(month from startdate)
  FROM workexpdeails ;
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "number of year month days"?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  enddate
  ,startdate
  ,(YEAR(enddate)*12+MONTH(enddate)) - (YEAR(startdate)*12+MONTH(startdate)) 
   as diffmonths 
  ,DATEDIFF(enddate, startdate) as diffdays
FROM workexpdeails ;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html